# Startup script in Rprofile throws 'function not found' errors

Tags: r, rprofile

I want R to load a certain file on initialization, so naturally I added a `source` command to my Rprofile so:

```
  .First <- function()
   {
         cat("\n   Welcome to R MotherFnorder!!!\n\n")
         setwd("/home/username/Code/R/")
       source("/home/username/Code/R/file.R")
   }
```

But now when I start `R` it throws a 'function not found' error for default functions like `runif` or `rnorm`. When I load the same file manually into the workspace I get no errors.

Comment: It is because you try to use functions not already imported in R, because your script is run... first.

Comment: Aha..... that kinda makes sense. So is there another function that is run after everything else in the beginning of the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need (or, really, *want*) to create a `.First` . If you put those lines into your `.Rprofile` they'll execute just fine.  -- With the proviso @Pascal pointed out, that any function called in your `file.R` must have its library loaded first.  So,
near the bottom of your `.Rprofile`, just put

```
library(whatever_packages_needed)
cat("\n   Welcome to R MotherFnorder!!!\n\n")
setwd("/home/username/Code/R/")
source("/home/username/Code/R/file.R")
```

EDIT: I cannot reproduce your problem.  I added these lines to the end of my .Rprofile:

```
#testing SO problem with libloading
library(stats)
runif(10)
```

And the console returns ten nice numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately your solution didn't work. I get exactly the same error.

{I already have the libraries used in the file called in its header; regardless, I added them again in the `.Rprofile` just to check, and it didn't make a difference.}

Comment: I tried the code mention in the updated notes, and this very same code also works for me. It seems this problem is specifically an issue with the way `source()` function is called in this context.

Comment: BUT it turns out what IS the problem is that I simply didn't have `library(stats)` in the header of my file. I assumed those functions were native to R I guess. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is that when `.First()` the packages are not yet loaded.

Although `runif` and `rnorm` might seem like default functions, they are actually part of the `stats` package. And as such, they are NOT available when `.First()` is called  (unless you specifically call that package from within `.First`)

... which also explains this:

> When I load the same file manually into the workspace I get no errors.

After `.First()` but *before* you have the chance to run anything manually, the default packages are attached.   And hence available to your functions when you call it manually.

---

The solution is to create a file (if it does not already exist) called 
`"~/.Rprofile"` and put in there the lines you currently have in `.First()`